# How to get User who hosts the event from a Calendly webhook?

Tags: javascript, calendly

I'm receiving an `invitee.created` webhook from Calendly, which contains Invitee details. I need to get a reference to the Calendly User that hosts the event, so that I can report on it in my application (e.g. keep track of meetings booked with a specific user). How do I do that?

Comment: Please include more details in your question. How is your Event Type set up, what invitee data (I assume that's what you mean by "user data") are you looking to get, where you're trying to send it, and how are you setting up the webhook subscription now?

Comment: I have done webhook setup also working well.
But in that webhook, I get all details which mention in doc but I want more details (user-id) in that webhook.  I get only email field which user entered manually. is there way to send user-id while user book meeting. So I get that user-id in webhook.

I want to update the database which user book meetings, that's why I need user id to update the database.

Comment: By "user id", do you mean the identifier of the Calendly user who is a host of the meeting, not the invitee?

Comment: No, i mean when any user book meeting. they need to add email right? , So in backend how i khow that which user book meeting.
I am adding calendly code to my site.
if somehow i get that userid which in my database then i can find which user book meeting.
is there any way to send some private information while user book meeting. So i get those information in my webhook

Comment: check this link. that show we can add custom field in URL. 
But how can I implement that in embed code in my website

Comment: https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/226766767-Pre-populate-invitee-information-on-the-scheduling-page#pre-populate-invitee-information-on-the-scheduling-page-0-0

Comment: The help center article describes custom questions that can be added to the booking form. I'm still not fully following. The person who books the event (invitee) enters their name and email, they are not necessarily a registered Calendly User. If you want to keep track of the User who is the host of the event, you need to call [Get Event](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/b3A6NTkxNDE2-get-event) endpoint and look at `event_memberships`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to know which Calendly User (or Users, for [collective events](https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/223145867-Multi-person-scheduling-options-for-teams)) the event was booked with, you need to call [Get Event](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/b3A6NTkxNDE2-get-event). The `event_memberships` array will contain a list of User references (URIs). Below is a more detailed step by step guide.

1. You received a webhook for the event `invitee.created`. [The payload](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/c2NoOjIxNDU0NTQ2-webhook-payload) looks something like this:

```json
{
  "created_at": "2020-11-23T17:51:19.000000Z",
  "created_by": "https://api.calendly.com/users/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
  "event": "invitee.created",
  "payload": {
    "cancel_url": "https://calendly.com/cancellations/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
    "created_at": "2020-11-23T17:51:18.327602Z",
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "event": "https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/GBGBDCAADAEDCRZ2",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "new_invitee": null,
    "old_invitee": null,
    "questions_and_answers": [],
    "reschedule_url": "https://calendly.com/reschedulings/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
    "rescheduled": false,
    "status": "active",
    "text_reminder_number": null,
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "tracking": {
      "utm_campaign": null,
      "utm_source": null,
      "utm_medium": null,
      "utm_content": null,
      "utm_term": null,
      "salesforce_uuid": null
    },
    "updated_at": "2020-11-23T17:51:18.341657Z",
    "uri": "https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/GBGBDCAADAEDCRZ2/invitees/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
    "canceled": false
  }
}
```

Here, the `payload` object is the [Invitee](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/c2NoOjM4OA-invitee). It has an `event` field that is a reference to the [Event](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/c2NoOjM3Ng-event) that the Invitee booked.

2. Make a GET call to `webhook_data.payload.event` - this will be the [Get Event](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/b3A6NTkxNDE2-get-event) operation. The response will look like this:

```json
{
  "resource": {
    "uri": "https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/GBGBDCAADAEDCRZ2",
    "name": "15 Minute Meeting",
    "status": "active",
    "booking_method": "instant",
    "start_time": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
    "end_time": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
    "event_type": "https://api.calendly.com/event_types/GBGBDCAADAEDCRZ2",
    "location": {
      "type": "physical",
      "location": "Calendly Office"
    },
    "invitees_counter": {
      "total": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "limit": 0
    },
    "created_at": "2019-01-02T03:04:05.678Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-01-02T03:04:05.678Z",
    "event_memberships": [
      {
        "user": "https://api.calendly.com/users/GBGBDCAADAEDCRZ2"
      }
    ],
    "event_guests": []
  }
}
```

The `event_memberships` array in the above payload is an array of Users with whom the event is scheduled (can be more than one, if it's a collective event). You can then do a GET on these User URIs or just compare these URIs with what you've previously saved in the database.